# How to get edge length(distance) from pgrouting DB

Tags: pgrouting, database

I have implemented pgRouting workshop and it's working fine. I need to get every edges length in kilometers to do some calculations I studied the ways table. It contains a length attribute, but it seems to be not what I exactly need.

Is there any place or way to get the length of each and every edge in kilometers or meters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the geometry column and the PostGIS function [`ST_Length_Spheroid`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Length_Spheroid.html) to calculate the length of the linestring in (kilo)meters:

`SELECT ST_Length_Spheroid( the_geom, 'SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]' ) / 1000 AS km FROM ways;`